# How do i make my fragment using a viewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

i have a fragment which uses AsyncTask to download the JSON and display several NEWS segments. Here i can slide up and down and view all the News segments. But i want to slide this horizontally and view the news segments one by one by sliding. As far as i know (i'm a beginner) i have to use a ViewPager adapter to achive this.But i don't know how.Please someone help me.

My fragment class

```
public class NewsDetailFragment extends Fragment {

    private View view1;
    private ArrayList<BaseElement> newsdetail;
    private LazyAdapter adapter;
    private Activity activity;
    private CommonVariable commonVariable;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newsdetail_fragment, container,
                false);

        activity = this.getActivity();


        commonVariable = (CommonVariable) activity.getApplication();

        view1 = (View) view.findViewById(R.id.list);


        dialog = new ProgressDialog(NewsDetailFragment.this.getActivity());
        dialog.setMessage("Loading News");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);

        new BackGround().execute();

        return view;
    }



public class BackGround extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            newsdetail = JSONServices.getNewsDescription();

            return null;

        } 

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
        /* check again */
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            commonVariable.setTheater(newsdetail);

            adapter = new LazyAdapter(newsdetail, activity,Element.NEWS_DETAIL.getType());

            ((AdapterView<ListAdapter>) view1).setAdapter(adapter);


            dialog.dismiss();

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

@Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    dialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

    }
}
```

My ViewPager adapter

```
public class ViewPageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private LinkedHashMap<String, BaseElement> item;
    private int page;
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private ViewPageAdapter(LinkedHashMap<String, BaseElement> item, int page,
            Activity activity) {
        super();
        this.item = item;
        this.page = page;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return item.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return view == (LinearLayout) object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
        View view = null;

        return view;
    }

}
```

PageAdapter

```
public class PageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    private ArrayList<BaseElement> item;
    private Activity activity;

    public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager,
            ArrayList<BaseElement> item, Activity activity) {

        super(fragmentManager);

        this.activity = activity;
        this.item = item;

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        // ------set fragment class for viewPager----------//
        Fragment fragment = new PageSectionFragment();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        // ---- setPage position as agument for PageSectionFragment
        // class---//
        bundle.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return item.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        FilmCategory film = (FilmCategory) item.get(position);

        Sihala sinhla = new Sihala(activity);

        return sinhla.getSinhalaString(film.getCategory());

    }
}
```

Comment: use `FragmentPagerAdapter`.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

Comment: i referred to it. No success

Comment: i think you have downloaded all news and showing them on list, after that you want the user to click on one of them and then swipe horizontally to see others, am i correct?

Comment: Use ViewPager only. no need for PagerAdapter. Add view pager into your layout

Comment: @CraZyDroiD See my answer and hope it will help you. you can share if I am wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this into your layout..

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:overScrollMode="never" />
```

Then Add this class into your Fragment class.

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<Fragment>();

        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        /*@Override
        public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return AlertSlideFragment.create(position);
        }*/

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
            tabFragment = new DummySectionFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position);
            tabFragment.setArguments(args);

            /*fragment = getRegisteredFragment(0);*/
            return tabFragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container,
                    position);
            registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            registeredFragments.remove(position);
            super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
        }

        public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position) {
            return registeredFragments.get(position);
        }
    }
```

Finally here is the DummySectionFragment

```
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            //          View rootView = null;
            /*View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tabbed_dummy,
                    container, false);
            TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                    .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                    ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));*/
            int screenNum = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
            //listAdapterAlert= new ListAdapterAlert(getActivity(), R.layout.alert_list);
            if(screenNum == 0) // 0 for recent
            {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_list,
                        container, false);
                TextView tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv);


            }
            else if(screenNum == 1) // 1 for by due date
            {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_list,
                        container, false);
                TextView tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv);


            }
            else if(screenNum == 2) // 2 for by campaign
            {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.campaign_alert,
                        container, false);


            }
            return rootView;
        }

    }
```

Hope it will help you.